# Django. Ajax. Is it wrong to send the csrf token like this?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm wondering if I'm doing it correctly and if it is safe. Usually I send the csrf token on an AJAX request using Jquery like this:

```
$.ajax({
       method: "POST",
       ...
       data: {...'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
       });
```

It works, but the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax) doesn't say anything about doing something like this. What is the difference between this and doing what the documentation recommends (getting the cookie and setting in on the header)?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of reading the value from the cookie then setting the header, is that it is less repetitive. It also works if your ajax request is in a static javascript file (if it's not a Django template then you can't use `{{ csrf_token }}`)

However, if you are happy adding the csrf token to the data of each ajax post request, that is fine, there is no problem doing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Disadvantages of using context variable over header are:

1. You should always include `csrfmiddlewaretoken` in `data`
2. In general, you cannot store your JS code in separate file, you are restricted to store it in templates.

Django docs provide you with copy-paste js code, you can include in your scripts at project level and forget about `csrfmiddlewaretoken`

Comment: But isn't it totally different to what the docs write? according to the docs one should get the cookie and set in on the header. Here I'm getting it on the DOM as a context variable and putting it on the request.body.

Comment: Yes, get from cookie and put to header. That's what provided js does. You don't need to explicitly set it in query data, django will handle things automatically